When rendering my model, it gets scattered
For a while i had problems rendering, namely blender would crash at the mere thought of rendering my obscure cathedral roof. i lowered the texture resolution and now i can render it in blender rather than using command promp. Allthough, when i go to material view it still crashes. that aside the main problem is that the render messes with the shape of my model, even after i made it a mesh and joined it (via ctrl + J) below i linked the picture of what it looked like before in material view, and what it looks like now in the render. i was able to go into material view before but not after i made it a full cone/roof. Any help would me tremendous.


Edit: I tried taking a picture in a different angle and got this, its like this because i had to increase the light power up to 5400 W. (its a beacon) interesting is that only the original piece is 100% contact, the original piece was duplicated 7 times to create the cone, my blender did crash so im wondering if its like this due to the crash or because of something else.

Check your modifiers. Maybe you see a different version in the vieport. The subdivision surface modifier for example is set to level 1 in the viewport by default and 2 when rendered. Set it to the render version inside the vieport to see the final result.

i havent added any modifiers, i have only used boolean to make individual detail inside the object. Do i just add the subdivision surface modifier to the entire model or what? Also if you have any ideas of to how i can stop my blender from crashing from the smallest of things like toggling to material mode or adding the subsurface modifier (after i try to add it, it crashes). Thank you for the responce.

You could try to apply the boolean modifier and try rendering again.

Are you able to provide us your scene? A crash is not easy to debug without having the scene in front of you. There can be several issues.
